# Passwords for Cloudera Quickstart VM users

Tags: cloudera-quickstart-vm

I wonder where can I see the passwords for different user accounts in Cloudera Quickstart VM, like yarn, hdfs user, etc.?

I am using version 5.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn, hdfs, etc are technical users. I'm pretty sure they don't have any password nor shell interface, as they don't need

If you're trying to change your current user to "hdfs", you'll have to try to do this from the root account. But you *shouldn't need* to do this, as they're not operational users.

Don't see them as you own user. If what you're looking for is the default credentials to connect to Hue and Cloudera Manager web interface, you should try cloudera/cloudera.

Answer (score 2):

As Cheloute has replied, yarn and hdfs are technical users, so they do not have a "normal" account with password or proper home directory (you can check this looking at the /etc/password and /etc/shadow files -this last one as root).

However, you may need to impersonate them, i.e., perform actions as if you where the hdfs or yarn user. For example, to change permissions in HDFS where hdfs is configured as a sort of superuser.

Let's assume that you want list HDFS directories as if you were the hdfs user. Also, assume that you are in a console as the "cloudera" user, that is the user by default in the quickstart VM.

Then, you have two options:
Option 1: In this option you open a new shell as hdfs user

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo su hdfs
bash-4.1$ whomai
hdfs
bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -ls
...

Option 2: perform a specific command as hdfs, without leaving the cloudera user
session:
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls
...